# Expresión regular para búsqueda no está funcionando

Tags: regex

Estoy tratando de usar expresiones regulares para buscar en una lista de opciones. Una lista de opciones podría ser:

```
ACDELCO - S19349356
BATERIA 30H-EU-950SMF

ACDELCO - 19375232
BATERIA 35-750 SMF

ACDELCO - 19314804
BATERIA AUTOMOTRIZ 24-950 AMP
```

Y el usuario puede buscar con los siguientes términos **bateria** y **amp** en el buscador.

El resultado que se esperaría sería el siguiente:

```
ACDELCO - 19314804
BATERIA AUTOMOTRIZ 24-950 AMP
```

La idea es devolver el ítem que tiene sí o sí las dos palabras que escribe el usuario en la búsqueda.

Para lograr este resultado estoy usando la siguiente expresión regular:

```
^(?=.*bateria)(?=.*amp)
```

Pero no me funciona :( Espero alguien me pueda dar una mano con esta duda. Muchas gracias de antemano por su ayuda.

Les comparto link donde la estoy armando: [regexr.com/5kr66](https://regexr.com/5kr66)

Comment: Veo que tu entrada se compone como de "bloques" de dos líneas cada uno. ¿Es esto importante? Es decir, quieres retornar el bloque completo de dos líneas o solo la línea que contiene las dos palabras. ¿Podría aparecer BATERIA en la primera línea y AMP en la segunda?

Comment: No, no es importante lo puse así con fines de visualización. En realidad es una sola línea :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya pude encontrar la solución, iba por buen camino, hasta que pude encontrar la expresión que necesitaba. La comparto por si alguien más la llegara a necesitar:

```
/^(?=.*\bbateria\b)(?=.*\bamp\b).*$/gi
```

Aquí está lista para testear: https://regex101.com/r/IZNMsY/1

Comment: No saldría un poco más entendible escribir: `^bateria\b.+\bamp$`?